# Secondary navbar items get displayed list style at smaller media screen

Tags: css

HTML code for the additional navigation bar which I do not want to hide at smaller screen.

```
<nav id="subnav" class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-default bg-light 
    text-uppercase custom-nav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav  ml-auto">
            <li>
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Language Equality</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">articles</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">help</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">download</a>
            </li>
         </ul>
</nav>
```

Here is my css

```
@media screen and (max-width: 460px) {
#subnav li{
    color: red !important;
    font-size: 15px;
    list-style: none !important;
    text-align: center !important;
    display: inline-block !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So if i see this right here, you like to have an normal list with list-style for bigger displays and on displays with smaler width then 460 px you like to have no list-style at all and put them also in a line.

For this result i used this HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
<title>Navigation</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<nav id="subnav" class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-default bg-light 
    text-uppercase custom-nav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav  ml-auto">
            <li>
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Language Equality</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">articles</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">help</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">download</a>
            </li>
         </ul>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

and this CSS code:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 460px) {
#subnav li{
    color: red !important;
    font-size: 15px;
    list-style: none !important;
    text-align: center !important;
    display: inline-block !important;
    }
}
```

[This is a picture of the style wenn the display is smaller then 460px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvGTB.png)

It shut be working. I thing you just misspellt something. Let me know if it worked (for me it does).

Comment: Yes, I do. Here is the line. <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

Comment: I do not want the items to be displayed in list item, in smaller or bigger screen. In bigger screen it get displayed as inline block by default. But in smaller screen it takes the style of list, which I do not want. Your code gives me a list style display. Anyway thanks for response.